# How order list of dates get from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, sql-order-by

I have a list sorted by date and I want to reorder it by clicking button. This date is taken from an object, I try this code, but it sorts like a simple number:

```
     // function to order and change button by click
         $scope.sortType = "CreationDate";
         $scope.sortReverse = false;
         $scope.buttonStyle = "icon ion-ios-time-outline";
         $scope.buttonPress = false;
         $scope.ordina = function() {

          if ($scope.sortType == "CreationDate") {
           $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
           console.log("riordinate");
          }

          $scope.buttonPress = !$scope.buttonPress;
          if ($scope.buttonPress == true) {
           $scope.buttonStyle = "icon ion-ios-time";
          } else {
           $scope.buttonStyle = "icon ion-ios-time-outline";
          }
         }
```

in html:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="object in allODA | filter: searchQuery | orderBy : sortType : sortReverse " href="#/app/ODA_Detail/{{object.caseTaskId}}">
```

any solutions???idea???

Comment: It is not very clear what you actually want. What do you mean by "it sorts like a simple number"? A date can be represented as a long value - which is a number - and you can sort by that value.

Comment: sorry for my english, the problem is that i can't order in the right way, because the item are ordered not by date, but like numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but here is an example to sort a table with dates, click on the title of the column to sort it.

https://jsfiddle.net/lisapfisterer/8pvqau4z/

This does not use ionic, you might need to adapt it.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <td data-ng-click="sortType = name; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
            Date
        </td>
        <td data-ng-click="sortType = name; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
            Name
        </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in allItems | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
            <td>{{item.date | date:"yyyy-MM-dd"}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you madame...just another question, in the database i have the data like a string "12/05/2015" and the orderBy is not correct is possible to change format in angular? like date:"dd-MM-yyyy"???i tried but not work!!!

Comment: How do you put the date in the database and how do you retrieve it? You should be working with date objects and not date strings.

Comment: you're right is a date string...how can i do to order like a date-time?